# Self sizing cell won't work with image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I have two prototype cells, one include a image, one not. The one without image works great with auto layout and self sizing cell. But one with image won't work. As you can see below. The image just cover some cells and make the layout a mess.
[image]

I am following this tutorial: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/08/07/self-sizing-table-view-cells.html

The code basically the same as the tutorial, in viewDidLoad

`tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`


`override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}`

I will upload the Main.storyboard. It may helpful to solve the problem.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmc709w7iizpzb0/Main.storyboard.zip?dl=0

Comment: From the screen shot it looks like the constraints on the image are probably wrong. Have you made sure it has a top and bottom constraint which ties it in with the other views and constrains its size? Also any constraint errors in the console? Search for "satisfy constraint" in the console log.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel Yes, I am sure. Can you help me looking into my storyboard and try to figure out the wrong constraint pls?

Comment: Find this constraint: Vertical Space -(5)- View - ImageView, make its priority to 1000.

Comment: Do you see any constraint errors when you run it in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a look at your storyboard.

You set the width of the image view to 332. This is bigger than the width of all iPhones except iPhone 6. It will struggle to maintain the constraints with that set.

In storyboard it actually still shows ok in the Preview window. However you can see the image wants to be off screen for everything except iPhone 6.

You might want to make the constrains for the top also tied to the persons image. Something like >=5 for the person image and for >=5 for the detail text. When the detail text is one line, the image goes over the person picture otherwise. However when the detail text is a few lines you want it below the detail text.

Comment: Thanks for you hint. Finally I solved the problem. I changed the priority of image view's width and height to 999.